# Conexão via socket, apenas quando necessário

Tags: php, javascript, socket, service-worker

Possuo uma aplicação web que precisa atualizar alguns valores frequentemente, pois as alterações tem de estar disponíveis quase em tempo real. Pra isso, executo via ajax uma rotina refresh.php a cada 15 segundos, que devolve as informações atualizadas. Tempo esse que aumenta se não houver atividade do usuário.

Pensei na possibilidade de criar um service-worker no browser (já que uso ele pra pwa também), e nele criar um web-socket, e então apenas quando houver uma atualização no servidor, criar um socket para os ip's dos usuários que estão logados (e salvo em um db), *apenas para dizer ao browser do usuário que existe uma atualização*, então o web-socket dispara a rotina em javascript que se conecta ao servidor e faz a atualização.

Não sei se seria possível criar o socket apenas pra informar que existe uma atualização, pois no caso, não quero deixar o socket aberto, criando a conexão apenas quando houver uma atualização das informações, o que no caso, deve acontecer pra vários usuários.

Alguém já precisou ou fez alguma coisa parecida, ou teria alguma outra ideia?